# Yup validation issue: Fields with their respective values present still says field is required

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am using Yup validation along with formik. I have both initial values and validationSchema prepared and everything works fine during creating a form. But on updating the form, even when the values are pre-populated in their respective fields, still some of the fields say 'abc field is required'. (name and type fields are required according to the below issue)

```
const initialValues = {
type: '',
name: '',
detail: {
    shareDetail: {
        tenantId: '',
        username: ''
    },
    blobDetail: {
        access: '',
        connection: ''
    }
}
}

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
name: Yup.string().required(),
type: Yup.string().required(),
detail: Yup.object().required().when('type', {
    is: (selectedType) => selectedType === 'SHARE',
    then: Yup.object({
        shareDetail: Yup.object({
            tenantId: Yup.string().required(),
            username: Yup.string().required()
        })
    }),
    is: (selectedType) => selectedType === 'BLOB',
    then: Yup.object({
        blobDetail: Yup.object({
            access: Yup.string().required(),
            connection: Yup.string().required()
        })
    })
})
}, ['type'])
```

and my jsx is:

```
 <Formik initialValues={formData || initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={onSubmit} enableReinitialize validateOnMount>
            {formik => {
                return (
                    <Form>
                        <h5>Source</h5>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-6'>
                                <FormControl control='select' label='Type *' placeholder='Enter Source Type' name='type' options={sourceTypes} AutoComplete
                                    value={getSourceTypeValue(formik.values.type)} onChange={e => handleSourceTypeSelect(e, formik.setFieldValue)} onBlur={() => handleSourceTypeBlur(formik.setFieldTouched)}
                                    outlineDanger={formik.errors.type && formik.touched.type ? 'mnd-danger' : ''} isDisabled={type !== 'createSourceButton'} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-12 mt-2'>
                                <FormControl control='input' type='text' label='Name *' placeholder='Enter Source Name' name='name'
                                    version={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name ? 'mnd-danger' : ''} disabled={type !== 'createSourceButton'} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-12'>
                                <FormControl control='textarea' type='text' placeholder='Enter Source Description' label='Source Description' rows='3' name='description' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        {formik.values.type === 'SHARE' && <>
                            <h5>Source Details</h5>
                            <div className="row mt-3">
                                {type === 'createSourceButton' && <div className="col-6 mt-2">
                                    <FormControl control='input' type='text' label='Tenant Id *' placeholder='Enter Tenant Id' name='detail.shareDetail.tenantId'
                                        version={formik.touched.detail && formik.errors.detail && formik.touched.detail.shareDetail.tenantId && formik.errors.detail.shareDetail.tenantId ? 'mnd-danger' : ''} />
                                </div>}
                                <div className="col-6">
                                    <FormControl control='input' type='text' label='Username *' placeholder='Enter Username' name='detail.shareDetail.username'
                                        version={formik.touched.detail && formik.errors.detail && formik.touched.detail.shareDetail.username && formik.errors.detail.shareDetail.username ? 'mnd-danger' : ''} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </>}
                        {formik.values.type === 'BLOB' && <>
                            <h5>Source Details</h5>
                            <div className="row mt-3">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <FormControl control='textarea' type='text' label='Connection String *' placeholder='Enter Connection String' rows='3' name='detail.blobDetail.connection'
                                        variant={formik.touched.detail && formik.errors.detail && formik.touched.detail.blobDetail.connectionString && formik.errors.detail.blobDetail.connectionString ? 'mnd-danger' : ''} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <FormControl control='select' label='Access *' placeholder='Select Access' name='detail.blobDetail.access' options={accessOptions}
                                        value={getAccessTierValue(formik.values.detail.blobDetail.accessTier)} onChange={e => handleAccessTierSelect(e, formik.setFieldValue)} onBlur={() => handleAccessTierBlur(formik.setFieldTouched)}
                                        outlineDanger={formik.touched.detail && formik.errors.detail && formik.touched.detail.blobDetail.access && formik.errors.detail.blobDetail.access? 'mnd-danger' : ''} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </>}
                        <div className="btn-toolbar float-right" role="toolbar">
                            <div className="btn-group mr-2" role="group">
                                <Button variant='outline' onClick={() => handleCancel()}>Cancel</Button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="btn-group mr-2" role="group">
                                {type === 'createSourceButton' && <Button type='reset' onClick={() => resetForm()}>Reset</Button>}
                            </div>
                            <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                                <Button type='submit' disabled={!formik.isValid} onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}>
                                    {type === 'createSourceButton' ? 'Create' : 'Update'}
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )
            }}
        </Formik>
```

Everything is working fine during the source creation scenario, but the update button is being disabled and if I check the formik errors, it says name and type are required fields even if their respective values are being populated correctly in the UI.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the required() from the beginning if the expression and add it to the end along with nullable() as for the nested objects validation discussed https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/501

Comment: @niiima, thanks for the suggestion. But that did not work.

Comment: I loaded formData with setTimeout of 10 milliseconds inside useEffect() and everything started to work fine. I was using useEffect() before as well with the conditional parameter to load formData but didn't use setTimeout. Not sure why it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the ["type"] as a dependency. I don't see a point to that,  there also might be a problem using yup.object() directly for the nested level, instead please change them to yup.object().shape({}).

Answer (score 1):

During the definition of the initial values you've set all the props for both cases of the `detail` property, it causes problem as with each value of the type property, both properties will still exist on the main object.
You might wand to try something like:

```js
const initialValues = {type: '', name: '', detail:{}};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
name: Yup.string().required(),
type: Yup.string().required(),
detail: Yup.object().when('type', {
    is: (selectedType) => !!selectedType && selectedType === 'SHARE',
    then: Yup.object.shape({
        shareDetail:Yup.object().shape({
            tenantId: Yup.string().required(),
            username: Yup.string().required()
        })
    }),
    is: (selectedType) => !!selectedType &&  selectedType === 'BLOB',
    then: Yup.object.shape({
        blobDetail: Yup.object().shape({
            access: Yup.string().required(),
            connection: Yup.string().required()
        })
    }),
}).nullable().required() // you might also need this.
}); //, ['type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be with `enableReinitialize` prop you are passing to `formik`. In Docs states:

> enableReinitialize?: boolean
>
> Default is false. Control whether Formik
> should reset the form if initialValues changes (using deep equality).

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean